# Why do I get this compile error in Java?

Tags: java

In java why is the following code not allowed by the compiler?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x;
        int x = 4;// the error is generated here

    }

}
```

Comment: We didn't need it in this case, but next time paste the compiler error as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the second

```
int x = 4;
```

Is attempting to  create a variable names "x" of type int, but this variable already exists ( created in the previous line )

Probably you would like to do:

```
int x;
x = 4;
```

( not using int in the second line )

That assigns the value 4 to x.

Or even better:

```
int x = 4;
```

That creates the variable x of type int and assign the value of 4.

Answer (score 11):

You have declared two `int` variables; both named `x`.  This is not allowed.

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    x = 4;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'll take them where I can get them :)

Comment: I voted up but would still like to see an explanation about redefining a variable...and maybe a description of the compiler error for super rep points